# When using dt-blob.dts to configure GPIO pins, which pin@pxx corresponds to #12 on the 40-pin header?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, gpio

My Raspberry Pi 3B runs Jessie-Lite. I would like to configure Physical pin 12/BCM pin 18/Wiring Pi pin 1 to be an output, set to low.

On Stretch, this can be done easily via config.txt
    gpio=18=op,dl

On previous versions, this is apparently done by editing the dt-blob.dts file (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/pin-configuration.md)

However, in the section for pins_3b1 or pins_3b2 (Pi 3 B), I cannot find a reference corresponding to my target pin (Physical pin 12/BCM pin 18/Wiring Pi pin 1). There is no pin@p12 or pin@p18. There is a pin@p1 but inside the videcore {} section.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[From https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=107&t=237796&p=1453560#p1453560]

The dt-blob is not meant to list all pins - just those with a specific function and that require a non-default value. If you were to initialise GPIO18 from the dt-blob to be an output driving low you would need to add something like:

```
pin@p18 { function = "output"; startup_state = "active"; termination = "no_pulling"; polarity = "active_low"; };
```